# Struggling with Admin check on session variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 pages. I need on "addproduct.php" to check whether the user is logged in as an admin. I have a login script. Apologies if this is a silly question but im brand new to PHP.

I want a user who reaches this page who is not logged in as an admin ('isadmin' is a row in the user database) to be redirected to the login page, and when someone is logged in as an admin for the page to display.

Login.php;

```
<?php
session_start();

$un = $_POST["username"];
$pw = $_POST["password"];

$conn = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=assign026;", "assign026", 
"ziSietiu");
$results = $conn->query("select * from users where username='$un' and 
password='$pw'");

$row = $results->fetch();
if($row == false)
{
echo "Incorrect password!";// There were matching rows
}
else
{
$_SESSION["gatekeeper"] = $un;

$_SESSION["isadmin"] = $row["isadmin"];

header ("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

And addproduct.php

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<?php
// Test that the authentication session variable exists
if(!isset($_SESSION["isadmin"]) || $row["isadmin"] == 1)
{
header('Location: login.html');
exit();
}
else
{
echo ($_SESSION["isadmin"]);
}
?>

<div>

<h2>Add new product</h2>

<form method="post" action="addproductscript.php">
  <p>Insert product here</p>
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" name="manufacturer" placeholder="manufacturer">
  <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description">
  <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="price">
  <input type="text" name="stocklevel" placeholder="stocklevel">
  <input type="text" name="agelimit" placeholder="agelimit">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>

 </div>
```

Comment: that line `if(!isset($_SESSION["isadmin"]) || $row["isadmin"] == 1)` will throw an error, because `$row` is not defined. So the script stops there.

Comment: have one file that you include everywhere where the user needs to be logged in (as admin?) That file does the check and the redirect. In that file you can first check if the `$_SESSION['isadmin']' is present, if not, check if given authToken matches database..

Comment: Row is defined in the first (login) script

Comment: those scripts are not connected (yet? not that I can see here). So unless you've removed some code `$row` is not defined in `addProduct.php`

Comment: and since you're new: Please learn 1st [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and second __do not store plain passwords to database__. Use password_hash and password_verify!

Comment: but row has been declared, do I need to declare it on every page?

Comment: Its just practice for uni work:) theres no risk of user data

Comment: _"uni work"_, _"theres no risk of user data"_  - so you are learning. Why don't you learn it right then??

Comment: _"on every page"_? No, but on every script unless they are included/required. Learn how script languages work. The scripts don't know of each other unless you combine them (to a "page").

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code `if(!isset($_SESSION["isadmin"]) || $row["isadmin"] == 1)`, the `$row["isadmin"]` is not defined thus it don't have any value.

What you can do is `if(!isset($_SESSION["isadmin"]) || $_SESSION["isadmin"] == 1)`

Comment: Now it redirects to the login page even when i log in as an admin.

Comment: get rid of the or clause. or make it `|| $_SESSION["isadmin"] == 0`